# Interpretation of CrystalDiskInfo Output

Tags: hard-drive, smart

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxs6g.png)
So... my HDD (D:) is a few years old now and I wanted to monitor how it aged.
In that time I used it pretty much and wrote much data on it but CrystalDiskInfo seems to say its fine.
Still I'd like to understand the "smart" table values and other forum threads or their website weren't helpful to someone who has no idea about hard drives.

So can someone explain to me what the integer and hexadezimal numbers mean exactly?

For example in this thread ( [What do the current, worst, and threshold SMART values mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/1127100/what-do-the-current-worst-and-threshold-smart-values-mean) ) the program marks "uncorrectable sector count" as yellow for a value of 100, but I have 100 too and its blue? Why?