# Can ATA error be safely ignored?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I want to repurpose 2 To Samsung SSD from a datacenter.
I checked the SMART status and it passes but still shows "ATA errors"
Can those be safely ignored ?

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Samsung based SSDs
Device Model:     SAMSUNG MZ7LM1T9HMJP-00005
Firmware Version: GXT5204Q
User Capacity:    1,920,383,410,176 bytes [1,92 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4c
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Mon Dec  2 16:35:16 2019 CET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x02) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        ( 6000) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x53) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 100) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   099   099   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       8
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       10344
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       12
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0013   099   099   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       43
179 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot   0x0013   099   099   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       8
180 Unused_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot 0x0013   099   099   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       6527
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0013   099   099   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       8
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0033   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Uncorrectable_Error_Cnt 0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       13
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0032   067   055   000    Old_age   Always       -       33
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   067   055   000    Old_age   Always       -       33 (Min/Max 12/45)
195 ECC_Error_Rate          0x001a   199   199   000    Old_age   Always       -       13
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
199 CRC_Error_Count         0x003e   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
202 Exception_Mode_Status   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
235 POR_Recovery_Count      0x0012   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       6
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       137385814130
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       50804040742
243 SATA_Downshift_Ct       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
244 Thermal_Throttle_St     0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
245 Timed_Workld_Media_Wear 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       65535
246 Timed_Workld_RdWr_Ratio 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       65535
247 Timed_Workld_Timer      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       65535
251 NAND_Writes             0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       185706652672

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 13 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 13 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 10336 hours (430 days + 16 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  00 51 01 b0 5b af 40  Error:  at LBA = 0x00af5bb0 = 11492272

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 30 00 80 5c af 40 00      05:34:42.098  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 01 10 00 00 40 00      05:34:42.098  READ LOG EXT
  60 50 00 80 5c af 40 00      05:34:42.098  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 80 00 00 5c af 40 00      05:34:42.098  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 30 00 d0 5b af 40 00      05:34:42.098  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 12 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 10336 hours (430 days + 16 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 80 5c af 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00af5c80 = 11492480

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 50 00 80 5c af 40 00      05:34:42.098  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 80 00 00 5c af 40 00      05:34:42.098  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 30 00 d0 5b af 40 00      05:34:42.098  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 30 00 80 5b af 40 00      05:34:42.098  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 01 10 00 00 40 00      05:34:42.098  READ LOG EXT

Error 11 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 10336 hours (430 days + 16 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 80 5b af 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00af5b80 = 11492224

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 50 00 80 5b af 40 00      05:34:42.098  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 80 00 00 5b af 40 00      05:34:42.098  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 30 00 d0 5a af 40 00      05:34:42.098  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 e0 00 d0 5b af 40 00      05:34:42.098  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 01 10 00 00 40 00      05:34:42.098  READ LOG EXT

Error 10 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 10336 hours (430 days + 16 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 d0 5b af 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00af5bd0 = 11492304

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 00 d0 5b af 40 00      05:34:42.098  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 e0 00 d0 5a af 40 00      05:34:42.098  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 01 10 00 00 40 00      05:34:42.098  READ LOG EXT
  60 00 00 d0 5a af 40 00      05:34:42.098  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 d0 59 af 40 00      05:34:42.098  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 9 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 10336 hours (430 days + 16 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 d0 5a af 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00af5ad0 = 11492048

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 00 d0 5a af 40 00      05:34:42.098  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 d0 59 af 40 00      05:34:42.098  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 d0 58 af 40 00      05:34:42.098  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 d0 57 af 40 00      05:34:42.098  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 01 00 80 56 af 40 00      05:34:42.098  READ FPDMA QUEUED

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
  255        0    65535  Read_scanning was completed without error
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

"Only" 64 Tb were written on the disk compared to the 1300 Tb announced by Samsung. Can this SSD be still safely used ?

Comment: 1300 TB sounds erroneous.  I believe that largest ever SSD is less than 100 TB.

Comment: It's not disk size, it's how much you can write multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### ATA errors can sometimes be ignored

A lot of different things can cause an ATA error.  Basically, whenever the controller can't talk to the SSD, an ATA error will occur.

The deciding factor on ATAs should be the accumulation rate.  If you have 30 historical ATA errors and that number never goes up, you can safely ignore the historical errors since you aren't accumulating new ones.  On the other hand, if you have the system running and you see the quantity of ATA errors increasing, you know there is an issue.

You can learn more about ATA errors here: https://kb.netgear.com/19392/ATA-errors-increasing-on-disk-s-in-ReadyNAS

Related: [What do the current, worst, and threshold SMART values mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/1127100/what-do-the-current-worst-and-threshold-smart-values-mean)