# Why does the smartctl output for a specific SSD wear count value have two different values: “Value” and “Worst”?

Tags: linux, windows, ssd, bug, physical-wear

I have bought a refurbished laptop (Dell Latitude) and run disc check on it disc (Hynix SC311 512GB) there are two different values for wear count, and this is not single instance as I have another laptop (Dell Latitude) with same disc model (Hynix SC311 256GB) and similar situation I checked on both smartctl and crystalDiscInfo.

I searched on internet but nowhere can I find anything similar
as `Wear_Leveling_Count` are always same or very similar values

1. Why are those values different ?
2. Is my disc at end of its life ?

```
smartctl 7.3 2022-02-28 r5338 [x86_64-linux-6.1.13-200.fc37.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-22, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     SK hynix SATA SSDs
Device Model:     SK hynix SC311 SATA 512GB
Firmware Version: 70000P10
User Capacity:    512,110,190,592 bytes [512 GB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      M.2
TRIM Command:     Available, deterministic, zeroed
Device is:        In smartctl database 7.3/5319
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sun Feb 26 15:41:25 2023 CET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x02) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        ( 4700) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x51) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0002) Does not save SMART data before
                    entering power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  80) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 0
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   166   166   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  5 Retired_Block_Count     0x0032   253   253   036    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   092   092   000    Old_age   Always       -       7299
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       1681
100 Total_Erase_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1387006
168 Min_Erase_Count         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       6
169 Max_Erase_Count         0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       54
174 Unexpect_Power_Loss_Ct  0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       112
175 Program_Fail_Count_Chip 0x0032   253   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
176 Unused_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot 0x0032   253   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0032   099   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       25
178 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Chip  0x0032   253   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
179 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot   0x0032   253   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
180 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1213
181 Non4k_Aligned_Access    0x0032   253   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  0x0032   253   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   253   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   253   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       191
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   029   010   000    Old_age   Always       -       29 (Min/Max 10/86)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x0032   253   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   253   253   036    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0032   253   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   253   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
204 Soft_ECC_Correction     0x000e   067   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       1167
212 Phy_Error_Count         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       24177594
233 Media_Wearout_Indicator 0x0032   002   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       99
234 Unknown_SK_hynix_Attrib 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       25201546768
241 Total_Writes_GB         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       46922154249
242 Total_Reads_GB          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       70059685890

SMART Error Log Version: 0
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      7299         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      7297         -
# 3  Extended offline    Aborted by host               50%      7255         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      7254         -
# 5  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         0         -

Warning! SMART Selective Self-Test Log Structure error: invalid SMART checksum.
SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 0
Note: revision number not 1 implies that no selective self-test has ever been run
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A value of 099 is very good (99% life time left). Worst 001 means Wear_Leveling_Count has been 001 in the past. So it's indeed strange. See this post https://superuser.com/questions/1127100/what-do-the-current-worst-and-threshold-smart-values-mean

Comment: Because your values are indeed strange I think the question is not a duplicate.