# Dell's message that my SSD harddrive is nearing end of life while CrystalDiskInfo says it's good. Who do I believe?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, smart

I have a Dell Inspiron which is almost 5 years old. It has one Disk which is a 256GB SSD.

Dell's Support Assist Program says my Harddisk is failing.

[image]

OTOH, CrystalDiskInfo says health of my Disk is good
[image]
I have read that unlike regular Harddisks, SSD's fail suddenly & not slowly. So how does Dell detect that my SSD is nearing end of life. Is it a message based on the fact that my SSD is nearing 5 years old or have they detected some problem? How do I figure this out?

Should I replace my SSD to be safe or should I let it be?

---

**S.M.A.R.T info:**

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Crucial/Micron Client SSDs
Device Model:     Micron 1100 SATA 256GB
LU WWN Device Id: 5 00a075 11bd0d9b7
Firmware Version: M0DL022
User Capacity:    256,060,514,304 bytes [256 GB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      M.2
TRIM Command:     Available, deterministic, zeroed
Device is:        In smartctl database 7.3/5528
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sun Aug 06 17:59:56 2023 IST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
AAM feature is:   Unavailable
APM feature is:   Unavailable
Rd look-ahead is: Enabled
Write cache is:   Enabled
DSN feature is:   Unavailable
ATA Security is:  Disabled, NOT FROZEN [SEC1]
Wt Cache Reorder: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
See vendor-specific Attribute list for marginal Attributes.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (  678) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   4) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   3) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x0035) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAGS    VALUE WORST THRESH FAIL RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocate_NAND_Blk_Cnt PO--CK   100   100   010    -    0
  9 Power_On_Hours          -O--CK   100   100   000    -    2505
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       PO--CK   100   100   001    -    15829
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  PO--CK   100   100   001    -    0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  PO--CK   100   100   001    -    0
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     PO--CK   076   076   010    -    366
187 Reported_Uncorrect      PO--CK   100   100   001    -    0
194 Temperature_Celsius     -O---K   060   041   000    -    40 (Min/Max 22/59)
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
238 Unknown_Attribute       ----CK   076   076   000    -    24
175 Program_Fail_Count_Chip PO--CK   100   100   000    -    0
176 Erase_Fail_Count_Chip   PO--CK   100   100   000    -    0
178 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Chip  PO--CK   100   100   000    -    0
180 Unused_Reserve_NAND_Blk PO--CK   000   000   000    -    2038
195 Cumulativ_Corrected_ECC POSR-K   100   000   050    Past 0
241 Total_LBAs_Written      PO--CK   100   100   000    -    79532484216
242 Total_LBAs_Read         PO--CK   100   100   000    -    88949374453
179 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot   PO--CK   100   100   000    -    0
                            ||||||_ K auto-keep
                            |||||__ C event count
                            ||||___ R error rate
                            |||____ S speed/performance
                            ||_____ O updated online
                            |______ P prefailure warning

General Purpose Log Directory Version 1
SMART           Log Directory Version 1 [multi-sector log support]
Address    Access  R/W   Size  Description
0x00       GPL,SL  R/O      1  Log Directory
0x01           SL  R/O      1  Summary SMART error log
0x02           SL  R/O     51  Comprehensive SMART error log
0x03       GPL     R/O  16383  Ext. Comprehensive SMART error log
0x04       GPL,SL  R/O      8  Device Statistics log
0x06           SL  R/O      1  SMART self-test log
0x07       GPL     R/O      1  Extended self-test log
0x09           SL  R/W      1  Selective self-test log
0x10       GPL     R/O      1  NCQ Command Error log
0x11       GPL     R/O      1  SATA Phy Event Counters log
0x13       GPL     R/O      1  SATA NCQ Send and Receive log
0x24       GPL     R/O   8000  Current Device Internal Status Data log
0x25       GPL     R/O   8000  Saved Device Internal Status Data log
0x30       GPL,SL  R/O      9  IDENTIFY DEVICE data log
0x80-0x9f  GPL,SL  R/W     16  Host vendor specific log
0xa0       GPL     VS   35328  Device vendor specific log
0xa1       GPL,SL  VS       3  Device vendor specific log
0xa2       GPL,SL  VS       1  Device vendor specific log
0xa3       GPL     VS   13824  Device vendor specific log
0xa4       GPL     VS     354  Device vendor specific log
0xa4       SL      VS      98  Device vendor specific log
0xa5       GPL     VS    8000  Device vendor specific log
0xa5       SL      VS      64  Device vendor specific log
0xa6       GPL     VS    8000  Device vendor specific log
0xa6       SL      VS      64  Device vendor specific log
0xa7-0xdf  GPL,SL  VS       1  Device vendor specific log
0xe0       GPL,SL  R/W      1  SCT Command/Status
0xe1       GPL,SL  R/W      1  SCT Data Transfer

SMART Extended Comprehensive Error Log Version: 1 (16383 sectors)
No Errors Logged

SMART Extended Self-test Log Version: 1 (1 sectors)
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2504         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1752         -
# 3  Short offline       Aborted by host               00%      1748         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1748         -
# 5  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1643         -
# 6  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1566         -
# 7  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1512         -
# 8  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1468         -
# 9  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1440         -
#10  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1436         -
#11  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1420         -
#12  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1366         -
#13  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1310         -
#14  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1257         -
#15  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1211         -
#16  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1165         -
#17  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1124         -
#18  Extended offline    Aborted by host               00%      1108         -
#19  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      1108         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.

SCT Status Version:                  3
SCT Version (vendor specific):       1 (0x0001)
Device State:                        Active (0)
Current Temperature:                    40 Celsius
Power Cycle Min/Max Temperature:     30/49 Celsius
Lifetime    Min/Max Temperature:     22/59 Celsius
Under/Over Temperature Limit Count:   0/0

SCT Temperature History Version:     2
Temperature Sampling Period:         1 minute
Temperature Logging Interval:        1 minute
Min/Max recommended Temperature:      0/70 Celsius
Min/Max Temperature Limit:           -5/75 Celsius
Temperature History Size (Index):    478 (15)

Index    Estimated Time   Temperature Celsius
  16    2023-08-06 10:02     ?  -
  17    2023-08-06 10:03     ?  -
  18    2023-08-06 10:04    35  ****************
  19    2023-08-06 10:05    35  ****************
  20    2023-08-06 10:06    36  *****************
  21    2023-08-06 10:07     ?  -
  22    2023-08-06 10:08     ?  -
  23    2023-08-06 10:09    34  ***************
  24    2023-08-06 10:10    46  ***************************
  25    2023-08-06 10:11    49  ******************************
  26    2023-08-06 10:12    49  ******************************
  27    2023-08-06 10:13    52  *********************************
  28    2023-08-06 10:14     ?  -
  29    2023-08-06 10:15     ?  -
  30    2023-08-06 10:16    38  *******************
  31    2023-08-06 10:17    46  ***************************
  32    2023-08-06 10:18    50  *******************************
  33    2023-08-06 10:19    51  ********************************
  34    2023-08-06 10:20    52  *********************************
  35    2023-08-06 10:21     ?  -
 ...    ..( 15 skipped).    ..  -
  51    2023-08-06 10:37     ?  -
  52    2023-08-06 10:38    47  ****************************
  53    2023-08-06 10:39    37  ******************
  54    2023-08-06 10:40    47  ****************************
  55    2023-08-06 10:41    51  ********************************
  56    2023-08-06 10:42    51  ********************************
  57    2023-08-06 10:43    51  ********************************
  58    2023-08-06 10:44     ?  -
 ...    ..(  8 skipped).    ..  -
  67    2023-08-06 10:53     ?  -
  68    2023-08-06 10:54    36  *****************
  69    2023-08-06 10:55     ?  -
 ...    ..(  6 skipped).    ..  -
  76    2023-08-06 11:02     ?  -
  77    2023-08-06 11:03    35  ****************
  78    2023-08-06 11:04    46  ***************************
  79    2023-08-06 11:05    36  *****************
  80    2023-08-06 11:06     ?  -
  81    2023-08-06 11:07     ?  -
  82    2023-08-06 11:08    42  ***********************
  83    2023-08-06 11:09     ?  -
 ...    ..(  2 skipped).    ..  -
  86    2023-08-06 11:12     ?  -
  87    2023-08-06 11:13    45  **************************
  88    2023-08-06 11:14    50  *******************************
  89    2023-08-06 11:15    50  *******************************
  90    2023-08-06 11:16    51  ********************************
  91    2023-08-06 11:17     ?  -
 ...    ..(  2 skipped).    ..  -
  94    2023-08-06 11:20     ?  -
  95    2023-08-06 11:21    37  ******************
  96    2023-08-06 11:22     ?  -
 ...    ..(  4 skipped).    ..  -
 101    2023-08-06 11:27     ?  -
 102    2023-08-06 11:28    34  ***************
 103    2023-08-06 11:29    49  ******************************
 104    2023-08-06 11:30     ?  -
 ...    ..(  4 skipped).    ..  -
 109    2023-08-06 11:35     ?  -
 110    2023-08-06 11:36    35  ****************
 111    2023-08-06 11:37     ?  -
 ...    ..(  6 skipped).    ..  -
 118    2023-08-06 11:44     ?  -
 119    2023-08-06 11:45    35  ****************
 120    2023-08-06 11:46    38  *******************
 121    2023-08-06 11:47    50  *******************************
 122    2023-08-06 11:48    54  ***********************************
 123    2023-08-06 11:49     ?  -
 ...    ..(  6 skipped).    ..  -
 130    2023-08-06 11:56     ?  -
 131    2023-08-06 11:57    47  ****************************
 132    2023-08-06 11:58    47  ****************************
 133    2023-08-06 11:59    48  *****************************
 134    2023-08-06 12:00    48  *****************************
 135    2023-08-06 12:01    49  ******************************
 136    2023-08-06 12:02     ?  -
 ...    ..(  2 skipped).    ..  -
 139    2023-08-06 12:05     ?  -
 140    2023-08-06 12:06    38  *******************
 141    2023-08-06 12:07    49  ******************************
 142    2023-08-06 12:08    40  *********************
 143    2023-08-06 12:09     ?  -
 ...    ..(  2 skipped).    ..  -
 146    2023-08-06 12:12     ?  -
 147    2023-08-06 12:13    35  ****************
 148    2023-08-06 12:14    48  *****************************
 149    2023-08-06 12:15    38  *******************
 150    2023-08-06 12:16     ?  -
 151    2023-08-06 12:17     ?  -
 152    2023-08-06 12:18    38  *******************
 153    2023-08-06 12:19    49  ******************************
 154    2023-08-06 12:20     ?  -
 ...    ..(  4 skipped).    ..  -
 159    2023-08-06 12:25     ?  -
 160    2023-08-06 12:26    46  ***************************
 161    2023-08-06 12:27     ?  -
 ...    ..(  3 skipped).    ..  -
 165    2023-08-06 12:31     ?  -
 166    2023-08-06 12:32    39  ********************
 167    2023-08-06 12:33    38  *******************
 168    2023-08-06 12:34    37  ******************
 169    2023-08-06 12:35    49  ******************************
 170    2023-08-06 12:36     ?  -
 171    2023-08-06 12:37     ?  -
 172    2023-08-06 12:38     ?  -
 173    2023-08-06 12:39    34  ***************
 174    2023-08-06 12:40    46  ***************************
 175    2023-08-06 12:41    50  *******************************
 176    2023-08-06 12:42     ?  -
 ...    ..(  4 skipped).    ..  -
 181    2023-08-06 12:47     ?  -
 182    2023-08-06 12:48    36  *****************
 183    2023-08-06 12:49    47  ****************************
 184    2023-08-06 12:50    50  *******************************
 185    2023-08-06 12:51    51  ********************************
 186    2023-08-06 12:52     ?  -
 ...    ..(  3 skipped).    ..  -
 190    2023-08-06 12:56     ?  -
 191    2023-08-06 12:57    41  **********************
 192    2023-08-06 12:58    49  ******************************
 193    2023-08-06 12:59    53  **********************************
 194    2023-08-06 13:00     ?  -
 ...    ..(  8 skipped).    ..  -
 203    2023-08-06 13:09     ?  -
 204    2023-08-06 13:10    36  *****************
 205    2023-08-06 13:11    46  ***************************
 206    2023-08-06 13:12     ?  -
 ...    ..(  6 skipped).    ..  -
 213    2023-08-06 13:19     ?  -
 214    2023-08-06 13:20    49  ******************************
 215    2023-08-06 13:21     ?  -
 216    2023-08-06 13:22     ?  -
 217    2023-08-06 13:23    38  *******************
 218    2023-08-06 13:24     ?  -
 219    2023-08-06 13:25     ?  -
 220    2023-08-06 13:26    36  *****************
 221    2023-08-06 13:27     ?  -
 222    2023-08-06 13:28     ?  -
 223    2023-08-06 13:29     ?  -
 224    2023-08-06 13:30    45  **************************
 225    2023-08-06 13:31    46  ***************************
 226    2023-08-06 13:32    41  **********************
 227    2023-08-06 13:33    50  *******************************
 228    2023-08-06 13:34     ?  -
 ...    ..( 12 skipped).    ..  -
 241    2023-08-06 13:47     ?  -
 242    2023-08-06 13:48    41  **********************
 243    2023-08-06 13:49     ?  -
 ...    ..(  4 skipped).    ..  -
 248    2023-08-06 13:54     ?  -
 249    2023-08-06 13:55    36  *****************
 250    2023-08-06 13:56    38  *******************
 251    2023-08-06 13:57    50  *******************************
 252    2023-08-06 13:58     ?  -
 ...    ..( 12 skipped).    ..  -
 265    2023-08-06 14:11     ?  -
 266    2023-08-06 14:12    47  ****************************
 267    2023-08-06 14:13    47  ****************************
 268    2023-08-06 14:14    48  *****************************
 269    2023-08-06 14:15     ?  -
 270    2023-08-06 14:16     ?  -
 271    2023-08-06 14:17    46  ***************************
 272    2023-08-06 14:18     ?  -
 ...    ..(  4 skipped).    ..  -
 277    2023-08-06 14:23     ?  -
 278    2023-08-06 14:24    36  *****************
 279    2023-08-06 14:25    37  ******************
 280    2023-08-06 14:26    48  *****************************
 281    2023-08-06 14:27    39  ********************
 282    2023-08-06 14:28     ?  -
 283    2023-08-06 14:29     ?  -
 284    2023-08-06 14:30    35  ****************
 285    2023-08-06 14:31     ?  -
 286    2023-08-06 14:32     ?  -
 287    2023-08-06 14:33    38  *******************
 288    2023-08-06 14:34     ?  -
 289    2023-08-06 14:35     ?  -
 290    2023-08-06 14:36    37  ******************
 291    2023-08-06 14:37    47  ****************************
 292    2023-08-06 14:38     ?  -
 ...    ..(  4 skipped).    ..  -
 297    2023-08-06 14:43     ?  -
 298    2023-08-06 14:44    46  ***************************
 299    2023-08-06 14:45    50  *******************************
 300    2023-08-06 14:46    52  *********************************
 301    2023-08-06 14:47    53  **********************************
 302    2023-08-06 14:48    53  **********************************
 303    2023-08-06 14:49     ?  -
 ...    ..(  6 skipped).    ..  -
 310    2023-08-06 14:56     ?  -
 311    2023-08-06 14:57    35  ****************
 312    2023-08-06 14:58    46  ***************************
 313    2023-08-06 14:59    50  *******************************
 314    2023-08-06 15:00     ?  -
 ...    ..(  6 skipped).    ..  -
 321    2023-08-06 15:07     ?  -
 322    2023-08-06 15:08    39  ********************
 323    2023-08-06 15:09    45  **************************
 324    2023-08-06 15:10    49  ******************************
 325    2023-08-06 15:11    52  *********************************
 326    2023-08-06 15:12     ?  -
 ...    ..(  4 skipped).    ..  -
 331    2023-08-06 15:17     ?  -
 332    2023-08-06 15:18    48  *****************************
 333    2023-08-06 15:19    49  ******************************
 334    2023-08-06 15:20     ?  -
 335    2023-08-06 15:21     ?  -
 336    2023-08-06 15:22    49  ******************************
 337    2023-08-06 15:23    51  ********************************
 338    2023-08-06 15:24    51  ********************************
 339    2023-08-06 15:25    52  *********************************
 340    2023-08-06 15:26    53  **********************************
 341    2023-08-06 15:27     ?  -
 ...    ..(  2 skipped).    ..  -
 344    2023-08-06 15:30     ?  -
 345    2023-08-06 15:31    44  *************************
 346    2023-08-06 15:32    48  *****************************
 347    2023-08-06 15:33    50  *******************************
 348    2023-08-06 15:34     ?  -
 349    2023-08-06 15:35     ?  -
 350    2023-08-06 15:36    41  **********************
 351    2023-08-06 15:37     ?  -
 ...    ..(  4 skipped).    ..  -
 356    2023-08-06 15:42     ?  -
 357    2023-08-06 15:43    47  ****************************
 358    2023-08-06 15:44    47  ****************************
 359    2023-08-06 15:45    48  *****************************
 ...    ..(  2 skipped).    ..  *****************************
 362    2023-08-06 15:48    48  *****************************
 363    2023-08-06 15:49    49  ******************************
 364    2023-08-06 15:50     ?  -
 365    2023-08-06 15:51     ?  -
 366    2023-08-06 15:52    38  *******************
 367    2023-08-06 15:53     ?  -
 368    2023-08-06 15:54     ?  -
 369    2023-08-06 15:55    38  *******************
 370    2023-08-06 15:56     ?  -
 371    2023-08-06 15:57     ?  -
 372    2023-08-06 15:58    36  *****************
 373    2023-08-06 15:59    45  **************************
 374    2023-08-06 16:00    48  *****************************
 375    2023-08-06 16:01    50  *******************************
 376    2023-08-06 16:02    53  **********************************
 377    2023-08-06 16:03     ?  -
 ...    ..(  2 skipped).    ..  -
 380    2023-08-06 16:06     ?  -
 381    2023-08-06 16:07    49  ******************************
 382    2023-08-06 16:08    49  ******************************
 383    2023-08-06 16:09    49  ******************************
 384    2023-08-06 16:10    36  *****************
 385    2023-08-06 16:11     ?  -
 386    2023-08-06 16:12     ?  -
 387    2023-08-06 16:13    40  *********************
 388    2023-08-06 16:14    48  *****************************
 389    2023-08-06 16:15     ?  -
 390    2023-08-06 16:16     ?  -
 391    2023-08-06 16:17    37  ******************
 392    2023-08-06 16:18    48  *****************************
 393    2023-08-06 16:19    52  *********************************
 394    2023-08-06 16:20    54  ***********************************
 395    2023-08-06 16:21    53  **********************************
 396    2023-08-06 16:22     ?  -
 397    2023-08-06 16:23     ?  -
 398    2023-08-06 16:24    39  ********************
 399    2023-08-06 16:25    47  ****************************
 400    2023-08-06 16:26    51  ********************************
 401    2023-08-06 16:27     ?  -
 ...    ..(  2 skipped).    ..  -
 404    2023-08-06 16:30     ?  -
 405    2023-08-06 16:31    36  *****************
 406    2023-08-06 16:32    46  ***************************
 407    2023-08-06 16:33    51  ********************************
 408    2023-08-06 16:34     ?  -
 409    2023-08-06 16:35     ?  -
 410    2023-08-06 16:36    37  ******************
 411    2023-08-06 16:37    47  ****************************
 412    2023-08-06 16:38    51  ********************************
 413    2023-08-06 16:39    51  ********************************
 414    2023-08-06 16:40     ?  -
 415    2023-08-06 16:41     ?  -
 416    2023-08-06 16:42    37  ******************
 417    2023-08-06 16:43    47  ****************************
 418    2023-08-06 16:44    49  ******************************
 419    2023-08-06 16:45    50  *******************************
 420    2023-08-06 16:46    51  ********************************
 421    2023-08-06 16:47     ?  -
 ...    ..(  5 skipped).    ..  -
 427    2023-08-06 16:53     ?  -
 428    2023-08-06 16:54    43  ************************
 429    2023-08-06 16:55    40  *********************
 430    2023-08-06 16:56    51  ********************************
 ...    ..(  2 skipped).    ..  ********************************
 433    2023-08-06 16:59    51  ********************************
 434    2023-08-06 17:00    52  *********************************
 435    2023-08-06 17:01    51  ********************************
 436    2023-08-06 17:02    42  ***********************
 437    2023-08-06 17:03     ?  -
 ...    ..(  4 skipped).    ..  -
 442    2023-08-06 17:08     ?  -
 443    2023-08-06 17:09    39  ********************
 444    2023-08-06 17:10    45  **************************
 445    2023-08-06 17:11    49  ******************************
 446    2023-08-06 17:12     ?  -
 ...    ..(  4 skipped).    ..  -
 451    2023-08-06 17:17     ?  -
 452    2023-08-06 17:18    36  *****************
 453    2023-08-06 17:19     ?  -
 454    2023-08-06 17:20     ?  -
 455    2023-08-06 17:21    39  ********************
 456    2023-08-06 17:22     ?  -
 457    2023-08-06 17:23     ?  -
 458    2023-08-06 17:24    39  ********************
 459    2023-08-06 17:25    45  **************************
 460    2023-08-06 17:26     ?  -
 ...    ..(  2 skipped).    ..  -
 463    2023-08-06 17:29     ?  -
 464    2023-08-06 17:30    45  **************************
 465    2023-08-06 17:31    47  ****************************
 466    2023-08-06 17:32    47  ****************************
 467    2023-08-06 17:33    49  ******************************
 468    2023-08-06 17:34    49  ******************************
 469    2023-08-06 17:35     ?  -
 470    2023-08-06 17:36     ?  -
 471    2023-08-06 17:37    45  **************************
 472    2023-08-06 17:38     ?  -
 473    2023-08-06 17:39     ?  -
 474    2023-08-06 17:40    36  *****************
 475    2023-08-06 17:41    49  ******************************
 476    2023-08-06 17:42    40  *********************
 477    2023-08-06 17:43    42  ***********************
   0    2023-08-06 17:44     ?  -
   1    2023-08-06 17:45    37  ******************
   2    2023-08-06 17:46     ?  -
   3    2023-08-06 17:47     ?  -
   4    2023-08-06 17:48    34  ***************
   5    2023-08-06 17:49     ?  -
   6    2023-08-06 17:50     ?  -
   7    2023-08-06 17:51    38  *******************
   8    2023-08-06 17:52     ?  -
   9    2023-08-06 17:53     ?  -
  10    2023-08-06 17:54    37  ******************
  11    2023-08-06 17:55     ?  -
  12    2023-08-06 17:56     ?  -
  13    2023-08-06 17:57    38  *******************
  14    2023-08-06 17:58     ?  -
  15    2023-08-06 17:59     ?  -

SCT Error Recovery Control command not supported

Device Statistics (GP Log 0x04)
Page  Offset Size        Value Flags Description
0x01  =====  =               =  ===  == General Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x01  0x008  4           15829  ---  Lifetime Power-On Resets
0x01  0x010  4            2505  ---  Power-on Hours
0x01  0x018  6     79532484480  ---  Logical Sectors Written
0x01  0x020  6      2021314004  ---  Number of Write Commands
0x01  0x028  6     88949374485  ---  Logical Sectors Read
0x01  0x030  6      1622864851  ---  Number of Read Commands
0x04  =====  =               =  ===  == General Errors Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x04  0x008  4               0  ---  Number of Reported Uncorrectable Errors
0x04  0x010  4           15798  ---  Resets Between Cmd Acceptance and Completion
0x05  =====  =               =  ===  == Temperature Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x05  0x008  1              40  ---  Current Temperature
0x05  0x010  1              40  ---  Average Short Term Temperature
0x05  0x018  1               -  ---  Average Long Term Temperature
0x05  0x020  1              59  ---  Highest Temperature
0x05  0x028  1              22  ---  Lowest Temperature
0x05  0x030  1              40  ---  Highest Average Short Term Temperature
0x05  0x038  1              36  ---  Lowest Average Short Term Temperature
0x05  0x040  1               -  ---  Highest Average Long Term Temperature
0x05  0x048  1               -  ---  Lowest Average Long Term Temperature
0x05  0x050  4               0  ---  Time in Over-Temperature
0x05  0x058  1              70  ---  Specified Maximum Operating Temperature
0x05  0x060  4               0  ---  Time in Under-Temperature
0x05  0x068  1               0  ---  Specified Minimum Operating Temperature
0x06  =====  =               =  ===  == Transport Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x06  0x008  4           34303  ---  Number of Hardware Resets
0x06  0x010  4              25  ---  Number of ASR Events
0x06  0x018  4               0  ---  Number of Interface CRC Errors
0x07  =====  =               =  ===  == Solid State Device Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x07  0x008  1              24  N--  Percentage Used Endurance Indicator
                                |||_ C monitored condition met
                                ||__ D supports DSN
                                |___ N normalized value

Pending Defects log (GP Log 0x0c) not supported

SATA Phy Event Counters (GP Log 0x11)
ID      Size     Value  Description
0x0001  4            0  Command failed due to ICRC error
0x000a  4            0  Device-to-host register FISes sent due to a COMRESET


Exitcode: 36 (0x24)
```

Comment: "lifetime is not limited by power on or service hours, but by the amount of combined writes made to a disk" https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/nl-nl/000071489/data-domain-solid-state-drive-has-reached-end-of-life-evt-storage-00016 I have no clue how reliable this is.

Comment: In any case, make backups and test if they work. Then make backups of your backups.

Comment: Your screenshot of CrystalDiskInfo contains virtually no relevant information. What’s important are the actual attribute values, which follow below.

Comment: @DanielB - I have updated the screenshot

Comment: Always trust the S.M.A.R.T info, as nothing else matters. Because CrystalDisk doesn't show the relevant S.M.A.R.T info in the screenshot, please post the terminal output from `smartctl -a /dev/sda` _(if two or more drives installed, verify `sda` is correct drive)_ by downloading [smartmontools for Windows](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Download#InstalltheWindowspackage). If you choose to install the context menu entries during install, right-click on `C:` → _Show more options_ → _SMART all info_

Comment: @JW0914 - Here is the output - https://pastebin.com/emn3zmLB

Comment: I would be worried due to the number of power cycles (>6) and resets (>13) per hour. I would check that you do not have any loose cables.

Comment: @Bib - are you referring to `Power_Cycle_Count 15829` & `Lifetime Power-On Resets`?

Comment: 15829 power cycles in 2505 hours doesn't sound healthy, except for some scenario where the PC is used for a minute or two, goes to sleep, sleeps for a while, and is used for a short time again, over and over. And 34303 hardware resets, 15798 of which are **  Resets Between Cmd Acceptance and Completion ** means the drive is resetting while trying to execute a command from the PC. Sounds like a very flaky power supply to me, or some hardware/firmware issue that causes the drive to reboot again and again.

Comment: You can believe that Dell is trying to sell you crap. And that you can't complain to *them* when you lose critical data from hereon out.

Comment: I'd say you have it backwards, "unlike regular Harddisks, SSD's fail suddenly & not slowly." except afaik I've never even had a bad sector on an SSD, let alone a complete failure, and one them is almost 10yo. SSDs mark their own bad sectors so you'd never even know anyway until it showed a weird capacity.

Comment: "it's usable life" and "it's best"? The Dell app doesn't seem very trustworthy.

Comment: @Mazura I wanted to push back on your statement about SSD's not failing.  I've had a number fail on me suddenly - in fairness these were more the older drives - although modern drives (I think the last one was a 2TB Crucial)  I've had were not immune either.  I learn't to be very careful of who I trust.  Also, on many SSD's the SMART shows the wear level, which can be helpful.  The failure modes I've seen on SSD's are either intermittent failing out of a RAID, but more commonly the drive shows up but is not accessible at all [ under Linux ]

Comment: @GuntramBlohm - drive rebooting means I would realize it, right? I mean it would mean the OS reboots, it cannot do it before my knowing it is doing so. This is my main laptop - I am in front of it 10 hours a day. It doesn't reboot every few minutes - there is something wrong with the data

Comment: @user93353 no, I'm talking about the drive itself rebooting. Talk about the drive reinitializing itself if you like that better (drives have their own CPU in form of a microcontroller, and that microcontroller reboots). The PC sends a command like "read those sectors" to the drive, the drive tries to do that, fails, reinitializes itself, tells the PC "hey, here I am!", the PC repeats the read command, and this time it works. The only thing you'd notice is a slight delay.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm - hmm - this means I should replace the SSD!! Is there another way to confirm this is happening?

Comment: @GuntramBlohm - is it surely because of the SSD itself & not anything else which is connecting the SSD to the Laptop?

Comment: With the high number of "power on resets" compared to "power on hours", my first bet would rather be a somewhat flaky power supply to the drive. The only way to test this would be to check the same SSD in another computer and/or try a new SSD in the same computer (note that the new SSD might need less power / be more robust against low voltage situations so might work even if the power supply is the culprit). I'd keep using the SSD, make sure to have daily backups (should do that anyway) and not move to a location where it's hard to get a replacement if it fails.

Comment: 2505 hours / 15829 is an average power on time of 9 minutes. Are you really using it so short?

Comment: When in doubt, replace it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**To me it seems the Dell Support tool is wrong** after examining the SMART data. The SMART data provide no reason for immediate alarm.

I am sorry I have to say **some of the other answers simply make incorrect assumptions about some of the SMART values**. This is understandable as SMART values and the way they are collected and calculated varies per vendor.

For example **one could argue the normalized values in this example ('Value' & 'Worst') look bad** as you normally don't want to see zeros here .. :

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAGS    VALUE WORST THRESH FAIL RAW_VALUE

180 Unused_Reserve_NAND_Blk PO--CK   000   000   000    -    2038
```

.. **while in fact they have no meaning** for this drive, as per [Micron's description](https://www.micron.com/-/media/client/global/documents/products/technical-note/solid-state-storage/tnfd22_client_ssd_smart_attributes.pdf) of the SMART attribute:

```
SMART ID 180 (B4h): Unused Reserve (Spare) NAND Blocks
Current Value
**This value is hard-coded to zero** (00h).
Worst Value
**This value is hard-coded to zero** (00h).
Raw Data
This value is calculated as:
URBC = BT - BG 
Where:
URBC = Total unused reserved block count.
BT = Total number of spare blocks when the drive left the factory. The 
spare block count represents the number of grown bad blocks the drive can 
handle in the field before it enters write protect. BG = Total number of 
grown bad blocks.
```

---

> I have read that unlike regular Harddisks, SSD's fail suddenly & not
> slowly. So how does Dell detect that my SSD is nearing end of life. Is
> it a message based on the fact that my SSD is nearing 5 years old or
> have they detected some problem? How do I figure this out?
>
> Should I replace my SSD to be safe or should I let it be?

**Any storage device can fail at any given moment**, it can go more or less in a predicable manner or with a bang. The way you phrased the question convinced me to vote to close the question as it invites for opinions IMO. Lucky for you, Superuser's audit system tells me I am wrong.

I still feel I was right, I see a lot of opinions and very few facts.

In the end **no one can tell** or predict ***when* your SSD will fail**, we can only tell you **it *will* fail**. FWIW, if we look purely at the SMART data available IMO there's not much to worry about.

---

Edit to address comments:

> Guntram Blohm in the comments in reply to the main question says that
> the disk is resetting every few minutes. "15829 power cycles in 2505
> hours". "And 34303 hardware resets, 15798 of which are Resets Between
> Cmd Acceptance and Completion".

For starters I'd be surprised if the Dell software is even considering these statistics. So IMO these do not offer an explanation why the Dell software is convinced the drive is about to fail. I still think the Dell software is wrong and likely interprets some of the normalized zero values incorrectly.

**An SSD does not have only two power states** (on/off). So while 2000 or so hours seem to suggest the drive has been running 2000 or so hours this may not be so, since it's possible **the drive only updates hours for a certain power-state**. If we look at the Micron documentation we read:

```
SMART ID 9 (09h): Power-On Hours Count
Current Value (8 bits)
This value is hard-coded to 100% (64h).
Worst Value (8 bits)
This value is hard-coded to 100% (64h).
Raw Data (48 bits)
This value gives the raw number of hours that the drive has been under power (online)
over its lifetime.
This attribute shall increment for each hour in the following link power state:
• SATA PHYRDY (Link Active)
This attribute may not increment for each hour in the following link power states:
• SATA Partial
• SATA Slumber
• SATA Device Sleep
```

During normal operation the SSD may switch between different states depending on use, and so in fact it may have been powered on 8000 rather than 2000 or so hours, but only 2000 hours were counted because the drive was in that particular power-state. I do not have statistics for this, so percentage of time the SSD is 'fully awake' or in a lower power state, I suppose it depends on what the SSD is used for. Perhaps my 8000 hours Partial/Slumber vs 2000 PHYRDY is conservative. Note that I'm just thinking out loud here.

Anyway, since we do not know the amount of hours the drive was 'powered on' it's hard to compare power-cycles to that value.

With regards to Partial and Slumber modes:

SATA specifications allow a host or device to place the interface (PHY) into reduced power states.

1. Partial: PHY is a reduced power mode where the exit time is less than 10 microseconds.
2. Slumber: PHY is in a reduced power mode, lower than Partial mode, and where the exit time is less than ten milliseconds.

I think a NVMe SSD has higher number of possible states.

**Resets** 'issue':

It's not without reason these aren't represented by SMART attributes: **they don't tell a lot about the state of the drive itself**. Resets are normal part of operations and only labeling these values as alarming makes the numbers seem serious perhaps. As I understand it resets are initiated by the HOST and they're just a 'normal' commands and not indicative for a fault in themselves.

So, drive received a command -> HOST for some reason sends hard or software reset command while commands were not yet completed.

Intel says (in relation to SSD's):

> The Number of Resets Between Command Acceptance and Command Completion
> statistic is a counter that records the number of Software Reset or
> Hardware Reset events that occur when one or more commands have been
> accepted by the device but have not reached command completion. The
> Number of Hardware Resets statistic is the number of hardware resets
> RECEIVED by the device. This means the reset came from the PC or
> laptop. None of these indicate an issue with the Intel® SSD. They are
> events that happen in the normal course of operation. The one
> exception might be ASR events. Steadily increasing ASR events might
> indicate an issue with the SATA port or the SATA cable.

So the ASR number is something worth monitoring, currently:

```
25  ---  Number of ASR Events
```

If that value stays stable it's probably something else not to worry about. For the rest RESETS probably sound more alarming than they are.

Again, all critical SMART attributes look okay to me and for every day use I'd limit myself to those.

Comment: Thank you. Guntram Blohm in the comments in reply to the main question says that the disk is resetting every few minutes. "15829 power cycles in 2505 hours". "And 34303 hardware resets, 15798 of which are Resets Between Cmd Acceptance and Completion". What do you think about this?

Comment: I'll edit answer for that, ok?

Answer (score 13):

You may want to provide us with the SMART Details for the drive so we can look at different attributes.  Based on the limited information presented I posit that the drive is OK, and Dell are being very conservative and/or trying to get money from you.  (That it calls your SSD a Hard drive should be causing suspicion.  It is reasonable to think a hard disk - which is spinning - may be expected to last 5 years.  I'm not so sure that this holds true for an SSD)

According to https://www.edgeelectronics.com/product_images/pdf/micron_1100_ssd.pdf that drive has a lifetime of 1.5 million hours (170 odd years!) and a TBW (ie amount you can write to it) of 120TB - you have done less then 40GB.

It is worth noting that this drive is an older drive and the controller on these may be less reliable then the type of memory is "TLC" which is not as good for TBW - and I suspect that the specs from Micron are somewhat optimistic, but even taking all this into account your drive seems fine based on the information provided.

You should make doubly sure you do regular backups (ideally into the cloud - as that is pretty close to instant, and you don't have that much data) - as you say, SSD's are fairly likely to fail without warning.

Its worth questioning why you are running Dell Support Assist.   You should read https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/dell-supportassist-bugs-put-over-30-million-pcs-at-risk/ and work out if it is worth the risk.  I would not run it (and it is not required for your PC to work)

Comment: You may want to read https://www.deceptology.com/hoax/how-to-know-if-the-hard-drive-failed-message-from-dell-supportassist-is-serious.html   - This gem may be particularly comforting - "[About Support Assist]... "some users have been reporting that the program is displaying a false positive for hard drive failure. This means that the program is incorrectly detecting a problem with your hard drive, even though there is no issue..."

Comment: 'SMART Details for the drive` - what are SMART details?

Comment: SMART details are a list of parameters and their values that SMART looks at to determine the status of the drive.   Have a look at https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskinfo/crystaldiskinfo-smart-information/ for an example of what they look like.

Comment: I have updated the screenshot with the full screen. Let me also look at how to get smart details.

Comment: I ran `diskdrive get status` & it says "Status OK". I am unable to figure out how to get the SMART attributes. Crytaldiskinfo page you linked only lists out the attributes but doesn't say how to make their application display the values?

Comment: *you have done less then 40GB.* - Looks like 37.9 TB, not GB.  Still fine, but maybe 1/4 of the lifetime, not a tiny fraction of a percent.

Comment: It's worth noting that the SA risk was greatly exaggerated. An attacker needed to be able to temper with the user traffic, while the user is updating the firmware. For this to be successful the attacker 1) need to know the user is using a vulnerable version of a very software of a specific vendor (DELL) and when; 2) be in the same network as the victim. While this is certainly possible, it's not something an opportunistic actor would do due to very very low ROI. And if you are targeted by a non-opportunistic attacker, you have to take way greater countermeasures than avoiding SA.

Comment: "then the type of memory is "TLC" which is not as good for TBW". Virtually all consumer drives these days are TLC (not to speak of QLC) because it's simply good enough with reasonable controllers. Those 120TB from Micron also sound reasonable to me. You can assume more than 3000 P/E cycles with the old TLC flash which would give you a write amplification of 6, which for usual client workloads is very, very reasonable. In practice SSDs do not die from P/E exhaustion. And even if they do, that's an incredibly harmless failure mode (you can still read all the data, just not write new stuff).

Comment: Isn't it true, replacing a 256GB SSD would cost little more than pocket change and leave you safe and secure to debate the technicalities without risk?

Comment: @robbiegoodwin Yes and no. Yes, in $$ terms of hardware,  This excludes labour costs, ewaste and  glosses over the other myriad of reasons a strong backup policy is vital and protects you - and which mitigate the need.

Comment: Of course a strong back-up policy is highly desirable and still, if there's a possibility that the main drive might be about to fail, would you prefer to replace it, or not?

While this is a superuser thread, what percentage of every-day users do you suppose have any back-up at all?

Comment: @davidgo deceptology dot com is crud. Just reading a paragraph or two of that page you linked made my brain hurt from all the stupid. It was written either by an AI, or by an incredibly stupid person with a terminal case of verbal diarrhoea.

Comment: @davidgo - what do you think of GuntramBlohm comments (on my question & not in any of the answers) that the drive is reinitializing every few minutes? If this SSD is nearing failure, then I would want to replace the laptop itself rather than the SSD because there are a few other issues with it. If the SSD is still good, then I would probably just get the other issues repaired.

Comment: Also he is saying that it may be a problem with the power supply to the SSD rather than the SSD itself, so replacing the SSD may not fix the issue. There is yet another comment saying there are 0 reserved sectors left while there is another comment saying there are 2038 reserved ones left. All diff opinions have left me very confused.

Comment: @user93353 if the deciding factor in replacing your PC is the $25 SSD - just replace the system and be done with it.

Comment: In my country, the SSD would cost around 50$ & also I would have to pay a technician to replace it. Also, the deciding factor is whether replacing it will fix the problem or not. If I was sure it would fix it, then I would replace it. But now with others saying that it might be problem with the power supply to the drive, I am not sure if it will fix the issue.

Answer (score 8):

Since some of the diagnostic tools report issues, and we don't have much insight in how they forecast disk failures or how accurate they are, personally I wouldn't bother too much about intrinsics of the diagnostic tools.

From a more practical perspective, things I would consider:

- the price of a new SSD is fairly low by now (mid-2023: less than $25/256G)
- replacing the old SSD while it's still working is a lot easier if you want to copy data to the new one (use a USB casing..) (*)
- being able to choose the point in time when I want to do the swap, rather than being forced to do that job when it's not convenient (**)
- good opportunity to upgrade (maybe 1TB, if you want..)
- be on the safe side

personally, I'd swap it out.

Then again, some people like living on the edge ;)

Anyway, I'd make sure to have a USB key prepared with an installable operating system - it's a lot less hassle to do that on a working computer.

---

(*) that is, if you have data on the disk that you want to preseve. If everything is in the cloud anyway, then it doesn't matter that much maybe.

(**) being able to choose the point is only useful if you can make time for it, and you're not always notoriously busy with everything. If you're anyway always completely booked out, then it doesn't really matter whether you get disrupted today or in 3 days.

Comment: First of all, you make 100% sure that you have a backup of everything on your computer in a form that you can restore onto a new computer if you have to. So if things go wrong, it's only "highly inconvenient" instead of "a complete disaster" .

Answer (score 5):

There's a lot of conflicting info there.
It (claims it) has only been on for 104 days, according to the SMART data. (That is, for 2505 hours).  (It seems that it powers off when idle, even for short periods.  That would be relatively consistent with the #12 Power_Cycle_Count of nearly 16k and the reported power on hours being much lower than OP says is accurate.)

The table largely shows ZERO data errors:  (Raw Value is 0 for all error count entries.):

```
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAGS    VALUE WORST THRESH FAIL RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocate_NAND_Blk_Cnt PO--CK   100   100   010    -    0
  9 Power_On_Hours          -O--CK   100   100   000    -    2505
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       PO--CK   100   100   001    -    15829
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  PO--CK   100   100   001    -    0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  PO--CK   100   100   001    -    0
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     PO--CK   076   076   010    -    366
187 Reported_Uncorrect      PO--CK   100   100   001    -    0
194 Temperature_Celsius     -O---K   060   041   000    -    40 (Min/Max 22/59)
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
238 Unknown_Attribute       ----CK   076   076   000    -    24
175 Program_Fail_Count_Chip PO--CK   100   100   000    -    0
176 Erase_Fail_Count_Chip   PO--CK   100   100   000    -    0
178 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Chip  PO--CK   100   100   000    -    0
180 Unused_Reserve_NAND_Blk PO--CK   000   000   000    -    2038
195 Cumulativ_Corrected_ECC POSR-K   100   000   050    Past 0
241 Total_LBAs_Written      PO--CK   100   100   000    -    79532484216
242 Total_LBAs_Read         PO--CK   100   100   000    -    88949374453
179 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot   PO--CK   100   100   000    -    0
```

So that's the good side.

About 80 billion sectors have been read and written.  (That's OK but surprising, usually there are several times more reads than writes.) That's about 320 TB.  160 TBW.  ***(corrected)***

On the danger side:

Your drive status is critical, based on the 0xB4 (=180 in decimal) line readings in both Crystal Disk Info and the smart results separately obtained:

```
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAGS    VALUE WORST THRESH FAIL RAW_VALUE

195 Cumulativ_Corrected_ECC POSR-K   100   000   050    Past 0

180 Unused_Reserve_NAND_Blk PO--CK   000   000   000    -    2038
```

0 is the worst possible value, 100 is the best.  This means there are dangerously few Unused, Reserved Blocks to use to replace blocks that have gone bad.  (The worst column shows the worst it has been so far in the life of the drive.)

The 195 line is also troubling.  See https://kb.acronis.com/content/9131. I'm not certain how to interpret it, but if it means ECC-corrected errors are happening one after another, that's bad.

Given that so much is inconsistent/ contradicts other stuff, I would not feel comfortable ignoring the issues.  Replace, as others have advised.  At least be sure to keep multiple current backups!

See: [What do the current, worst, and threshold SMART values mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/1127100/what-do-the-current-worst-and-threshold-smart-values-mean) - confirms what I'm saying about the meaning of the values, and adds lots more info.

Comment: `Theres a lot of conflicting info there. It's only been on for 104 days. (That's 2505 hours)` - it's a 5 year old laptop & there has been a minimum of 8 hours usage each & every day of those 5 years!

Comment: `This means there are dangerously few Unused, Reserved Blocks to use to replace blocks that have gone bad.` - will this improve if I delete unnecessary stuff on the disk?

Comment: Wow, that's very odd.  https://kb.acronis.com/content/9109 is clear.  It couldn't have been replaced? Deleting stuff would not be expected to help, as that would make for more unused blocks, but not for more unused, reserved blocks.

Comment: I believe that many SMART attributes are drive dependent - Your 9131 and 9109 links applies to Samsung, Seagate, Fujitsu, Maxtor and WD **Hard Drives** from circa 2010 - so the information you are imputing to them is likely incorrect. (An authorative datasheet for this drive)  does not actually mention these values, weirdly enough ( https://www.micron.com/-/media/client/global/documents/products/technical-note/solid-state-storage/tnfd22_client_ssd_smart_attributes.pdf).

Comment: Also https://www.reddit.com/r/labtech/comments/7ul7q4/false_smart_failures_on_ssd_drives/ seems to also indicate this is a false positive

Comment: This drive has never been replaced in the 5 years

Comment: The drive is indeed at death's door - Dell is correct, the firmware's overall health status and CrystalDiskMark are wrong. No amount of deleting, trimming or formatting will help. The key facts are "FAIL: Past" for ECC and "0" unused reserve, the latter of which would get you bad health in CrystalDiskMark if this were an NVMe drive

Comment: *About 80 million sectors have been read and written.*  **No, it is 80 BILLION!** Which at 512 bytes per sector is 40 TB of data. Not 0.3TB.

Comment: There are 2038 unused reserve blocks, not 0.  The 0 is a severity analysis of the raw value; only the raw value is a number of blocks.  So far no reserved blocks have been used (parameter 178).

Comment: @Dark Is it really credible to argue Dell SupportAssist- a known insecure and very buggy application - specifically known to cause false positives on SSD failures in this scenario know more then Micron (better known as  Crucial) about the products Micron designed?

Comment: Too much wrong with this answer, hence my downvote. Normalized values for unused spare blocks are hard coded at zero for Micron SSD's, this alone invalidates half the story.

Comment: Weird.  I recall fixing the GB/TB error.  Forgot to save, I guess.  Downvote was fair.  Fixed.

Comment: HEY!!  @BenVoigt & co: I did NOT say there were 0 unused reserve blocks!!!  It's CORRECT that 0 is the worst possible value, 100 is the best.  Do you dispute that?  (OTOH, the larger the raw value for this parameter, the better.)

Comment: @WHO'sNoToOldRx4Covid-CENSORED: You interpreted that line to mean "there are dangerously few unused reserved blocks remaining" which is simply false.  Not a single reserved block has been used (see parameter 178).  Dark was the one who actually claimed "0 unused reserve".  My comment corrected both of you.

Comment: Not quite. Oh, yes that was Dark who said there were 0 unused reserve blocks. So you agree that "It's CORRECT that 0 is the worst possible value, 100 is the best," with respect to the VALUE of Attrib #180?   (We agree about what parameter 178 says. That's why the first sentence in my post is: "There's a lot of conflicting info there.")